# Can we make [filter-branch] a synonym for [git-filter-branch] please?

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, synonym-request, tag-synonym-process

There are currently

- [163 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/git-filter-branch/info) tagged with [git-filter-branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-filter-branch)
- [15 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/filter-branch/info) tagged with [filter-branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/filter-branch)

  - There actually used to be about 26 questions tagged with this, but I started removing them, but after about 14 minutes of this, I decided it wasn't really worth my time.

There's [currently a proposal](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/git-filter-branch/synonyms) for making `[filter-branch]` into a synonym for `[git-filter-branch]`. It needs 3 more upvotes to approve.

Please vote to approve this, or if you disagree, please explain why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Done!​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

Comment: Ah, that was quick, thank you and many blessings to you and your descendants!